# How to get query parameters in Elm?

Tags: elm

In my Elm program, I'd like to initialize my model based on the query string.

For example, if the query string is `?w=3&h=5` I'd like to have:

```elm
initialModel =
  { width = 3
  , height = 5
  }
```

Is that possible to achieve this in Elm, or the only way to do this is to get the query parameters in Javascript and pass them via a port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in core library way to access the URL. You can use ports and the community library [jessitron/elm-param-parsing](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/jessitron/elm-param-parsing/1.0.3/).

If you also want to set the URL, you can again use ports, or you can use the History API, for which there are bindings in [TheSeamau5/elm-history](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/TheSeamau5/elm-history/latest).

Answer (score 12):

Elm 0.19

---

For elm 0.19 the below concept is the same. Both of these packages still exist but have been moved and relabeled as the official [`elm/url`](https://github.com/elm/url) and [`elm/browser`](https://github.com/elm/browser) libraries.

Elm 0.18

---

This example uses [`evancz/url-parser`](https://github.com/evancz/url-parser/tree/2.0.1) and [`elm-lang/navigation`](https://github.com/elm-lang/navigation). There are a few kinks that aren't straightforward in the documentation, but I've explained them briefly below. The example should speak for itself.

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html as H exposing (..)
import Navigation exposing (Location)
import UrlParser as UP exposing ((</>), (<?>), top, parsePath, oneOf, s, stringParam, Parser)
import Maybe.Extra as MaybeExtra exposing (unwrap)


type Route
    = UrlRoute (Maybe String) (Maybe String)
    | NotFoundRoute


type Msg
    = UrlParser Navigation.Location


type alias Model =
    { location : Route
    , w : String
    , h : String
    }


type alias SearchParams =
    { w : Maybe String, h : Maybe String }


main =
    Navigation.program UrlParser
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = (\_ -> Sub.none)
        }


init : Location -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init location =
    let
        currentPath =
            parseLocation location
    in
        ( initialModel currentPath
        , Cmd.none
        )


parseLocation : Location -> Route
parseLocation location =
    case (parsePath matchers location) of
        Just route ->
            route

        Nothing ->
            NotFoundRoute


matchers : Parser (Route -> a) a
matchers =
    UP.map UrlRoute (UP.s "index" <?> UP.stringParam "w" <?> UP.stringParam "h")


initialModel : Route -> Model
initialModel route =
    { location = route
    , w = MaybeExtra.unwrap "" (\x -> Maybe.withDefault "" x.w) (parseParams route)
    , h = MaybeExtra.unwrap "" (\x -> Maybe.withDefault "" x.h) (parseParams route)
    }


parseParams : Route -> Maybe SearchParams
parseParams route =
    case route of
        UrlRoute w h ->
            Just { w = w, h = h }

        NotFoundRoute ->
            Nothing


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UrlParser location ->
            ( model
            , Cmd.none
            )


view : Model -> Html msg
view model =
    div []
        [ h1 [] [ text "URL Info" ]
        , div [] [ text ("W is: " ++ model.w) ]
        , div [] [ text ("H is: " ++ model.h) ]
        ]
```

The "trick" is to create another type alias to place your query params inside of. In the above example I've created the type `SearchParams`. After creating this type we just use an `initialModel` that takes in the `currentPath`.

From there, our model can extract the query params with `Maybe.withDefault` (it needs to be a `Maybe` type because the params may not be there). Once we have our data in the model we just print it out in the view.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately jessitron/elm-param-parsing doesn't work with Elm 0.18.

Use elm-lang/navigation package:

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/navigation/latest/Navigation

https://github.com/elm-lang/navigation/tree/2.1.0

especially this function:

```
program
    : (Location -> msg)
    -> { init : Location -> (model, Cmd msg), update : msg -> model -> (model, Cmd msg), view : model -> Html msg, subscriptions : model -> Sub msg }
    -> Program Never model msg
```

In the second parameter you can see "init : Location -> (model, Cmd msg)". This should handle reading of initial URL. To complement that, first parameter is a function which gets called every time URL changes.

(I am aware it's an old question, but this link popped out when I was looking for the solution to the same problem and accepted answer didn't help)